# Variadic template function and reference types

Tags: c++, c++11

As part of a DSL for an OpenCL binding I have to count the arguments given to a function `f` and handle them seperately, in the code below this would be `h`. The function should accept LValues as well as RValues for most types. However, for some types (here: `int`) only LValue references are acceptable (in the real code these are objects that might need to initialised lazily).

My problem: how do I get rid of that `const_cast`? `f(T...)` doesn't work, neither does `f(T&...)` or `f(T&&...)`

```
template<typename T>
void h(int i, const T &x) {/* generic things */}

void h(int i, const int &x) { const_cast<int&>(x) = 123; }

template<int i> void g() {}

template<int i, typename H, typename... T>
void g(H &x, T... xs) {
    h(i, x);
    g<i + 1>(xs...);
}

template<typename... T>
void f(const T&... xs) { g<0u>(xs...); }

#include <cassert>
int main(int, char**) {
    int x = 1;
    f(x, 2.0 + 3.0, 'c');
    assert(x == 123);
}
```

Comment: Remove the `const` from your parameter types?

Comment: if I do this, it breaks on an RValue like `2.0 + 3.0` because that can't be used with `double&`, it needs `const double&`.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question I found a solution, but I don't understand why the signature is `int &&` instead of `int &` (doesn't seem to matter though?)

```
template<typename T>
void h(int i, T x) {cerr << i << "=" << x << endl;}

void h(int i, int &&x) {
    x = 123;
    cerr << i << "=" << x << " (new)" << endl;
}

template<int i> void g() {}

template<int i, typename H, typename... T>
void g(H &&x, T &&... xs) {
    h(i, std::move(x));
    g<i + 1>(xs...);
}

template<typename... T>
void f(T &&... xs) { g<0u>(xs...); }
```

Also, with `h(int, T&)` the overload `h(int, int&&)` is called for all three arguments, `int`, `double` and `char`, which looks very suspicious to me (or is this because `int x = 2.0, y = 'a';` works, too?)

Comment: `T&&` is commonly referred to as a "universal reference". Reference collapsing rules allow it to be instantiated for both lvalues and rvalues.

Comment: ok, I only knew them as “RValue references” and didn't even think of using them for LValues before...

Comment: @pascal: Reference collapsing occurs in template context.  If you have a specific type (`int&&` for example), then it is an rvalue-reference, not a universal reference.  Only when paired with a template type parameter do you get the universal behavior.

Comment: In the template function definitions of `g(H &&x, T &&... xs)`and `f(T &&... xs)`would an additional `move`be useful? That is, instead of `g<i + 1>(xs...)`have `g<i + 1>(std::move(xs...))`. And for `f(T &&... xs)`, have `g<0u>(std::move(xs...)`in place of `g<0u>(xs...)`.